# How to send database attachment field as email attachment

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 database of customers and I am trying to send them a welcome email with their counter signed agreement as an attachment. I am storing their agreement as an attachment field on the customer table. The files will be .docx

`MyMail.Attachments.Add Me.Agreement` receives an error: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

I've read a ton of articles that are similar to my issue, but I can't seem to find anything that works.

```
'Open Outlook
Set MyOutlook = New Outlook.Application

'Creates the e-mail
Set MyMail = MyOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Populates the fields
MyMail.To = Me.[ContactEmail]
MyMail.CC = Me.[repEmail]
MyMail.Subject = "Welcome to the evaluation program"
MyMail.Display
MyMail.HTMLBody = Me.[ContactName] & ":" & vbCr & vbCr & [strMessageBody] & vbCr & MyMail.HTMLBody
MyMail.Attachments.Add Me.Agreement

'Display it first
MyMail.Display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Attachments.Add method requires a filename in the form "C:\Myfile.txt". You could either save your files as filenames in the database and keep the actual files in another folder or you could save out the files from the attachment field using the SaveToFile method.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll start by trying out the SaveToFile method and see if I can get that working. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up using the SaveToFile method.